# How can I choose the capacitor for a class B power amplifier?

Tags: power-amplifier

In this class B power amplifier, the capacitor is fully charged when Qmax = C. Vcc and discharges in a negative period.  Why is the capacitor full with Vcc instead of another voltage value?

[image]

Comment: That's not a class AB amplifier, looks like a class B.  Can you clarify your question, not sure I understand it as written.

Comment: Thank you. I edited.

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, the capacitor doesn't charge and discharge at all. The voltage of the capacitor remains almost unchanged when operating because this is a coupling capacitor. If you measure the voltage of the capacitor, you will see a DC value.

Answer (score 3):

The capacitor forms a highpass filter in combination with the load resistance. It's main purpose is to block the DC output component from loads which don't cope well with DC, e.g. speakers.

Its value must be large enough that 1/RC is smaller than the lowest frequency that you want to pass.